# How to extend the Smarty class right

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I have a Problem with Smarty.

I have made this class:

```
<?php
require_once(INCLUDE_PATH.'smarty/Smarty.class.php');

class IndexPage extends Smarty {
    public $templateName = 'index.tpl';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->showTemplate();
    }

    public function showTemplate() {
        self::display('index.tpl');
    }
}
?>
```

But why it doesn't works?

Here is the Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load
template file 'index.tpl'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('index.tpl', NULL, NULL, NULL, true)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\classes\IndexPage.class.php(14): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('index.tpl')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\classes\IndexPage.class.php(10): IndexPage->showTemplate() 
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\index.php(3): IndexPage->__construct()
#4 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

Comment: is this index.tpl where smarty expects to find it?

Comment: The "INCLUDE_PATH = D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\", the class is in "D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\classes\IndexPage.class.php" and the template "D:\xampp\htdocs\aiondb\lib\templates\index.tpl"

Comment: I have a common.php with this Code inside: http://pastebin.com/qN9uuq0r

Comment: Try using the full absolute path in your class.

Comment: You think I should make "INCLUDE_PATH . 'templates/index.tpl' " ?

Comment: Yes try it. I've extended smarty class and I use the full path to my directories and files. It makes it a lot easier to not confuse smarty.

Comment: Okay, they found the index.tpl but not the header/footer.tpl :/

Comment: Where is header/footer.tpl being called?

Comment: What version of smarty are you using? Also it sounds like you should set your template location in the extended class.

Comment: The header.tpl/footer.tpl is called in the index.tpl